# RGoogleTrends: SSL certificate issue, verify that the CA cert is OK

Tags: r, ssl-certificate, rcurl

Before proceeding, please download `RGoogleTrends_0.2-1.tar.gz` [here](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleTrends/), which is Duncan Temple Lang's website.

Reproducible example (or, at least, I hope it **will be** reproducible by someone):

```
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
Sys.setenv(TZ = 'UTC')

# In the command line below please insert the path of your RGoogleTrends package

install.packages('C:/.../RGoogleTrends_0.2-1.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')
install.packages('DBI')
install.packages('quantmod')
install.packages('RCurl')
install.packages('RSQLite')

require(DBI)
require(RCurl)
require(RGoogleTrends)
require(RSQLite)
```

I've created a Google account with these parameters:

```
login = cicciopafolr@gmail.com
password = econfol1
```

Then the `RGoogleTrends` code:

```
# The example below comes from RGoogleTrends package.
## Not run: 
# Picks up c(login = password) from GooglePassword option
# i.e. set with
options(GooglePassword = c(cicciopafolr = 'econfol1'))
g = googleSignIn()
ans = getGTrends("coupon", curl = g)
## End(Not run)
```

Result of the code:

```
> g = googleSignIn()
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

My `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RSQLite_0.11.3        RCurl_1.95-4.1        bitops_1.0-5          quantmod_0.4-0       
 [5] TTR_0.21-1            Defaults_1.1-1        DBI_0.2-6             RGoogleTrends_0.2-1  
 [9] Matrix_1.0-11         lattice_0.20-13       MASS_7.3-23           truncnorm_1.0-6      
[13] numDeriv_2012.9-1     xts_0.9-3             zoo_1.7-9             RcppArmadillo_0.3.6.3
[17] Rcpp_0.10.2           rcom_2.2-5            rscproxy_2.0-5       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.2  tools_2.15.2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your example. Calling `getGTrends` threw an error, but not one associated with SSL. You might try running the following before you run your code:

```
opts <- list(
  capath = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"));
options(RCurlOptions = opts)
```

If that doesn't resolve your problem, then try this:

```
opts <- list(
  capath = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), 
  ssl.verifypeer = FALSE);
options(RCurlOptions = opts)
```

If either of those work, then you probably have the problem described at http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html (search on the page for 'When I try to interact with a URL via https, I get an error of the form'). **Note that page's warning about the dangers of using `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE`.**

Incidentally, it appears the the version of the package maintained at https://github.com/omegahat/RGoogleTrends has been updated more recently than the one at the repository you gave.

Comment: I succeeded in running `g = googleSignIn()` using your second tip about `RCurl`'s options... but now `getGTrends()` crashes my RStudio session every time I launch it. Is that the same issue you got?

Comment: Yes. The same thing was happening to me. Run it in the regular R console to get the error message.